# Binding components to wixlib in VS2010 + Wix 3.6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.6, wixlib

I'm converting our wix project from 3.0 to 3.6.  The wixlibs generated in the VS2010/wix3.6 set up are not binding the components to the wixlib.  In VS2008/wix3.0 there is a checkbox in the library wixproj properties GUI under the Build tab to force binding files into the library file.  I'm not seeing this in the VS2010/wix3.6 wixproj Build tab.

Where did this move and/or how can I force files to be bound?  This is pretty fundamental to how our modularized applications consume upstream modules.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710611/is-it-possible-to-include-source-files-in-a-wixlib/4711087#4711087) mentions the same tab/checkbox.

Comment: And a partial answer:  Add <LibBindFiles>True</LibBindFiles> to the wixproj appears to do the trick.  Still curious about the UI change in VisualStudio 2010 if anyone has information on that however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add the -bf to your VS2010 project(s) that build the .wixlib and it will blob(embed) the files into the .wixlib file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be late to the answer, but editing the .wixproj file is very ugly.
I found that adding the -bf flag in the

Project Properties -> Tool Settings -> Additional Parameters -> Librarian

did the trick wonderfully.
(Just to save some schmuck from another hour of research like myself)